# What is it: Could not find method dataBinding() for arguments?

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding

Could not find method dataBinding() for arguments [true] on BuildType$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=buildFeatures, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType$AgpDecorated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use the dataBinding section inside the the android section like the following

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
         enabled true
    }
}
```